# unwanted margin in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and encountered this weird situation where everything goes well on desktop, but on a Samsung Galaxy S5, or other similar size displays (360 x 640 or 640 x 360 for this particular example) I get this weird margin on the right side I cannot get rid of.[image]

Although my body element scales to the exact width.

Screen capture is taken into Chrome browser.
The code is live at: http://11784vic.bphp56.webrahost.ro/

Comment: why don't you set margin-right:0 for this size?

Comment: I have `margin:0` on the body element if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: Don't link to your website. Instead, create a barebone fiddle to demonstrate the problem here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry for that but I'm not sure if I could exactly replicate the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: @AngelinCalu give overflow-x:hidden;

Comment: @AngelinCalu if it solve your problem let me know

Comment: @mkafiyan it has overflow-x:hidden for mobile displays

Comment: I see it without margin in Chrome (Galaxy S5)

Comment: So, it seems that I was given the overflow-x: hidden to the wrong element. If added to `body` tag it works !! Thank you!

Comment: @AngelinCalu no overflow:hidden to body but your problem come from row class you have to use col-xs-12

Comment: @AngelinCalu is it solve your problem? can I write my answer?

Comment: Yes, but please elaborate what you previously wrote about col-xs-12!

Comment: @AngelinCalu look you use .row it gives margin-right and left -15px to your body and that's make your problem . you can use col-xs-12 it is for mobile size or you can give it style by your self or just simply remove negetive margin for this part.

Comment: @AngelinCalu and also pay attention when you use col-lg-12 browser don't understand that must set width:100% for all window with you have also give theme col-xs-12 for mobile size and col-sm-12 for tablet and col-md-12. never forget this. it change your style in different windows size.

Comment: @AngelinCalu problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add overflow:hidden to your body but in my openion you have to solve the source of problem and it comes from class row cange it to col-xs-12 
it may change your style but it's right way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue, without `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: Yes. I did updated as suggested, but without `overflow-x:hidden` I have the same issue.

Comment: hum so did you remove negetive margin of row? I still see class row in your code

Comment: I'm sure changing the row class is not an option. That it's supposed to have those negative margins:     https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1611

Comment: yes your right so just use the overflow-x until I found where is your problem. I ping you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122733/discussion-between-mkafiyan-and-angelin-calu).

Answer (score 0):

There are only `col-lg-12` classess in your div add `col-md-12` and `col-sm-12`. This will solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue, without `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: If you are using bootstrap classes and didn't modified anything then you don't have to write any additional styling. Just use the predefined classes and all will work magically.